# Redirection from module to application

Tags: zend-framework

how can we go back form one module to parent application in ZEND. I use this code:-

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => '', 'action' => '')); ?>
```

Comment: Did you mean default module instead of "parent application"?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a 'module' key to the URL array, you can easily traverse modules.  If you're trying to get to the "Parent" (the default module, perhaps?), you'd change your code to:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index)); ?>
```